# Creating User Specific Participation Pages in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models; Examinations, Participation and User. They are connected with has many through relationship - and the Participation model is a joint model.

I can list all participations or show a specific participation (see my controller below) - but my goal is to create a page named "My Participations" - where users can see only their participations. Participation model has a "user_id" field for this purpose but I don't know how to create this kind of page or method in controller.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the my model structure:

**examination.rb =>**

```
class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :users, :through => :participations

  has_many :bookings
  has_many :exam_centers, :through => :bookings
end
```

**participation.rb =>**

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :examination
end
```

**user.rb =>**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :participations
  has_many :examinations, :through => :participations
end
```

As you can see I'm having "Participation" as a join model between Examination and User models. They have **has many through** rich relationship.

**participations_controller.rb =>**

```
#encoding: utf-8

class ParticipationsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_participation, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :get_examination

  def get_examination
    @examination = Examination.find(params[:examination_id])
  end

  def index
    @participations = @examination.participations
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @participations.to_csv }
      format.xls # { send_data @examinations.to_csv(col_sep: "\t") }
    end
  end

  def show
    @participation = @examination.participations.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @participation = Participation.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @participation = @examination.participations.new(participation_params)
    @participation.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @participation.save
        format.html { redirect_to [@examination, @participation], notice: 'Başvuru işleminiz başarıyla tamamlandı! Lütfen başvurunuzu kontrol ediniz ve onaylayınız. Onaylanmamış başvurular geçersiz sayılacaktır!' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: [@examination, @participation] }
      else
        render 'new'
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @participation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participation.update(participation_params)
        format.html { redirect_to [@examination, @participation], notice: 'Başvurunuz Başarıyla Güncellendi! Lütfen başvurunuzu kontrol ediniz ve onaylayınız. Onaylanmamış başvurular geçersiz sayılacaktır!' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: participation.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @participation.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to examination_participations_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def approve_application
    @participation = @examination.participations.find(params[:id])
    @participation.is_approved = true
    @participation.save
    redirect_to examination_participation_path, notice: 'Kaydınızı Onayladınız! Tebrikler!'
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_participation
      @participation = Participation.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def participation_params
      params.require(:participation).permit(:user_id, :examination_id, :payment_status, :language_preference, :exam_center_preference, :disability)
    end
end
```

**Schema Structure =>**

```
  create_table "examinations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "shortname"
    t.datetime "exam_date"
  end

  create_table "participations", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "examination_id"
    t.boolean  "payment_status"
    t.string   "language_preference"
    t.string   "exam_center_preference"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "first_name",             default: "", null: false
    t.string   "last_name",              default: "", null: false
    t.string   "id_number"
  end
```

**Routes =>**

```
devise_for :users

resources :examinations do
  resources :participations do
    member do
      get :update_profile_information
      get :approve_application
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new controller, `MyParticipationsController` for example, and create `index` action to display participations for the current user.

app/controllers/my_participations_controller.rb

```
class MyParticipationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @participations = current_user.participations
  end
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :my_participations, only: [:index]
```

You may remove the `index` action in the `ParticipationsController` if needed.